# DataFactory - Manipulate file name in copy activity - Add current date prefix to sink

Tags: azure-data-factory

I new to DataFactory so this might be a simple question.

I wish to add a timestamp to a copied file when i copy it to archive folder.
All done on the same Blob storage.

Example :
source file : file.csv
sink file   : file24062022.csv

So far i tried to add a
@concat('whitelist_',formatDatetime(utcnow(),'dd-MM-yyyy'),'.csv')

My question is:
How do i add a timestamp to a file using Copy activity?

Here is the copy behavior

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a dataset parameter for the file name in the sink dataset.

[image]

2. Pass the dataset parameter value dynamically from the copy data activity sink.

`@concat(formatdatetime(utcnow(),'dd-MM-yyyy'), 'csv')`

[image]